# Difference between rolling, rolling with additional batch and immutable deployments in AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am using Elastic Beanstalk to handle my deployments.

I read the explanation for these deployment options but it was not quite clear to me.

Could someone explain it in simpler words?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

I think this will help a little bit.

`Immutable` – starts by deploying your application code to a single newly created EC2 instance. Once the deployment succeeds on the first instance, the remaining number of instances required to create a parallel fleet are created and the application code is deployed to them. After the deployment succeeds on the entire parallel fleet, instances running the old application version are terminated 25% at a time. This deployment policy ensures that the impact of a failed deployment is minimal (i.e.: a single EC2 instance) and enables your application to serve traffic at full capacity during an ongoing deployment.

`Rolling with an additional batch` – starts by deploying your application code to a single batch of newly created EC2 instances. Once the deployment succeeds on the first batch of instances, the application code is deployed to the remaining instances in batches until the last batch of instances remains. At this point, the last batch of instances is terminated. This deployment policy ensures that the impact of a failed deployment is limited to a single batch of instances and enables your application to serve traffic at full capacity during an ongoing deployment.

`Rolling` – starts by deploying your application code to a single batch of existing EC2 instances. Once the deployment succeeds on the first batch, the application code is deployed to the remaining instances, in batches. This deployment policy ensures that the impact of a failed deployment is limited to a single batch. However, since no new instances are created during the deployment, your application can serve traffic at a reduced capacity (i.e.: a single batch of instances are out of service at any given time during the deployment).

Comment: Thanks! Is it possible to switch to the new "new parallel fleet" in Immutable method by switching from old fleet straight away and not 25percent at a time. ? I dont want my application to serve old code + new code at the same time.

Comment: No you cannot do that using Immutable you have to use "All at once" deployment for that.

Comment: Blue/Green is more suitable for you

Comment: I have a question in rolling updates is the traffic coming from clients redirected to newly deployed instances and then only old one are terminated after processing the running requests? Hope I am clear

Comment: Yes after the deployment is successful then those instances will start getting traffic. You have to make sure there is sanity check in place so that the application is working before the newly deployed instances start receiving actual traffic

Answer (score 11):

I found [this post](https://blog.shikisoft.com/which_elastic_beanstalk_deployment_should_you_use/) easier to understand than the accepted answer, so here's my take on it.

Ordered by high-to-low risk, and calling the deployed versions `v1` to `v2`:

- All at once: Replace all `v1` with `v2` at the same time. Failure not handled.
- Canary: A `v2` is deployed and observed.  If successful, all remaining `v2` instances are deployed immediately.
- Rolling: Replace `v1` instances with `v2` instances one at a time. Watch for failures.
- Rolling with batch: Create some new `v2` instances. If successful, roll out on `v1` instances. When all are `v2` instances, scale back to original size.
- Immutable: Don't change `v1` instances. Create same number of `v2` instances. Wait for success, then stop `v1` instances.
- Blue/green: Instead of operating on an environment in-place, create a new environment (network, etc.) fully provisioned with `v2`, and switch over when ready.