# AWS Beanstalk Restarts Instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-codepipeline

I have created a pipeline using AWS Codepipeline, Github, Jenkins and AWS Elastic Beanstalk (Docker) running a nodejs application. Everytime a build is triggered in AWS Codepipeline and deployment done on the Elastic Beanstalk instance, it's corresponding EC2 instance is terminated and another one created afresh and we only want the app to be deployed without termination of EC2 instance. What could be the cause for termination on every build/deployed?

Comment: Do the deployment of your new version cause a huge CPU peak? It can be a reason why Beanstalk terminate your instances (it consider them as not healthy)

Comment: @Xavier I will try and post if it works, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I switched to Immutable deployment and stopped experiencing the issue as explained here: [Difference between rolling, rolling with additional batch and immutable deployments in AWS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38656595/difference-between-rolling-rolling-with-additional-batch-and-immutable-deployme)

Turns out that Rolling deployments can cause the timeouts especially that I had a single instance needed

Answer (score 0):

how many instances do you have in your beanstalk and what deployment method are you using: All at Once, Rolling, Rolling with an Additional Batch or Immutable?

With these responses, we can continue the research.

Comment: Single instance is running but a maximum of 4 has been set. Deployment is (Rolling 30%)